# angular routing with asp .net mvc dynamic menu web api

Tags: angular-routing

I want merge angular routing in asp .net mvc . can any one help me do this

[image]

my app file as above here i have area dashboard and dashboard mvc views and controllers. i want to create a menu as flows

- dashboard
- areaDashboard

html page

```
<ul>
    <li> <a href="#dashboard"> dashboard page </a></li>
    <li><a href="#Areas/areadashboard"> areaDashboard </a> </li>        
    </ul>
```

app.js file

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp' , ['ngRoute']);
    app.app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/dashboard1', {
            templateUrl: 'Dashboard1',
            controller: 'dashCtrl'
        })
        .when('/area1/area1dashboard', {
            templateUrl: 'Area1/Area1Dashboard',
            controller: 'areaDashCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: ''
        });  }).controller('dashCtrl' , function($scope){
 $scope.message =" this is dashboard controller";
}).controller('areaDashCtrl' , function($scope){
 $scope.message =" this is area dashboardcontroller";
});
```

dashboard/index.cshtml

```
<script type="text/ng-template"  id="Dashboard1">
<div ng-controller="dashCtrl">
{{message}}
</div>
```

area1/area1Dashboard/index.cshtml file

```
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="Area1/Area1Dashboard">
    <div ng-controller="areaDashCtrl">
    {{message}}
    </div>
</script>
```

i'm getting error like this

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/ng/areq?p0=dashCtrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
at Error (native)
at http://localhost:3376/Scripts/angular.min.js:6:416
at pb (http://localhost:3376/Scripts/angular.min.js:22:41)
at Sa (http://localhost:3376/Scripts/angular.min.js:22:128)
at http://localhost:3376/Scripts/angular.min.js:80:25
at link (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular-route.min.js:7:180)
at $ (http://localhost:3376/Scripts/angular.min.js:73:46)
at L (http://localhost:3376/Scripts/angular.min.js:61:495)
at g (http://localhost:3376/Scripts/angular.min.js:54:326)
at http://localhost:3376/Scripts/angular.min.js:53:388(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:107(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:80$ @ angular.min.js:73L @ angular.min.js:61g @ angular.min.js:54(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:53(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:55m @ angular.min.js:60v @ angular-route.min.js:6m.$broadcast @ angular.min.js:135(anonymous function) @ angular-route.min.js:11(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:118m.$eval @ angular.min.js:132m.$digest @ angular.min.js:129m.$apply @ angular.min.js:133g @ angular.min.js:87L @ angular.min.js:91A.onload @ angular.min.js:92
```

Comment: Do you have the app declared such as <html data-ng-app="myApp">? May be basic, but I can't see the declare from the code you have given.

Comment: Also, here is a great read on using the two together.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806029/Getting-started-with-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Par.